# webbrowser disable script debugging in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6, scripting

I want to disable script errors from popping up in a VB6 application. (I have VB6 installed on this machine).

1. Currently, if I navigate to a particular page, it pops up saying "INternet Explorer Script Error: An error has ocurred in the script on this page" ... "Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?"
2. Setting the webbrowser1.silent to 'true' does *not* work. Instead all that happens, is instead of displaying an error message, it starts up the actual 'script' debugger, and then exits the program. On a machine without the (visual studio) debugger, it still pops up a message asking to use the debugger, i.e., on Vista, (when silent is set to true).
3. Manually changing the 'disable script debugging (other)' (and regular one), doesn't seem to working in MSIE (also testing version 6.0 for xp users).

How do I disable script errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case you're still looking, try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/279535

Answer (score 4):

```
WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

(The above code will Not work in VB6)

---

(Try this instead)

```
WebBrowser1.Silent = True
```

Answer (score 2):

The webbrowser.silent can be reset to true when the application is run if you've set it in the design window.  You may have to reset it to true when starting the application (ie: at runtime) and see if that works.

Comment: Ok... Thanks for your response, but when I compile it (run a compiled app) -- if I get an error, basically it just launches the JIT compiler (on Vista), and on XP launches the debugger there (I think I mentioned that in the original question). Do you know/have any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I Think It's That You Need

Write This Code In Your Form_Load Or Everywhere You Want

```
WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain your answer?